# ASCII-only keyboard for Android

Tags: java, android

I use the following code to sow soft keyboard on Android (the code works):

```
InputMethodManager keyboard = (InputMethodManager)activity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
View view = activity.getWindow().getDecorView();
keyboard.showSoftInput(view, 0);
```

How can I modify it in order the keyboard to display ASCII characters only (or just display it without a button to switch to native layout)?